# Reference on 3-Manifold Link Surgery

Tags: manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

I'm looking for a low dimensional topology reference with extensive treatment of Dhen Surgery presentations and obtaining 3-manifolds via surgery on a link.

Comment: Rolefson - knots and links...I guess that's the standard one.

Comment: The reference I turn to for Dehn surgery type stuff is Gompf and Stipsicz's  Kirby calculus and 4-manifolds.

Comment: Nikolai Saveliev's book on 3-manifolds also has a clear treatment of this.